# why cookies are always disabled in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cookies, cross-browser

i am using

```
 navigator.cookieEnabled
```

in JavaScript to determine whether cookies enabled or not on client. its working fine on all browsers except IE. Please help am i using wrong method for  identifying about cookies is there something wrong with IE 10

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way I can think of to check whether cookies are enabled is to set a cookie in your response from the server in the first place, and check that it's set on the client via `document.cookie`. According to [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15582757/157247), there's no point in checking `cookieEnabled`, it doesn't provide correct information.

For instance, if your server includes this header in the response serving the page:

```
Set-Cookie: cc=1; Max-Age=3600
```

...then your JavaScript code can check like this:

```
if (/\bcc=/.test(document.cookie)) {
    // They appear to be enabled
} else {
    // Not so much
}
```

Comment: i am checking for cookie on login page itself on click of login button . My problem is it works fine in chrome, firefox but not in IE

Comment: @Rutu: By "it" do you mean `cookieEnabled`? That's why I'm suggesting actually checking for a cookie. Nothing says "cookies are/aren't enabled" like "I do/don't see a cookie I set."

Comment: even if i enable cookies on IE still it gives false in IE 10. Am i missing anything