# Cookies disable doesn't work in Internet Explorer 11 using advance setting

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

I have Window 7- 64bit machine, I am using below Javascript code to check cookies enable in IE 11.

```
     var areCookiesEnabled= function () {
        //check by using navigator
        var cookieEnabledNavigator = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;
        //By Setting Test Cookies
        document.cookie = "testcookie";
        var cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false;
        return (cookieEnabled && cookieEnabledNavigator);
      }
```

### It works when do below setting to disable cookies.

[image]

### But it doesn't work with below setting to disable cookies.

[image]

[image]

- Do I need to update cookies check code?
- Does the IE 11 in Window 10 make any sense? Is    Yes, Then why option is there for other Windows?

Any solution would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Duplicate still valid - yes you need debug your code for setting it and reading it again

Comment: I have debugged it, It sets and reads cookies when disable using advance option. Its duplicate in sense of cookies disable code but its for IE Advance cookies disable setting issue. In the link you have mark it as duplicate, there is no such conversation for advance setting in IE. Could you please review?

Comment: @mplungjan Can you please help me to update code as I have already checked for both Navigator and By explicitly setting and reading cookies?

Comment: I have reopened, but do not get your issue. Does this code work for you? `var cookies = 
    ("cookie" in document && (document.cookie.length > 0 ||
    (document.cookie = "test").indexOf.call(document.cookie, "test") > -1))` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125330/javascript-navigator-cookieenabled-browser-compatibility

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks It would really help me to find issue. NO Its same thing, there is cookies I have seen as value for document.cookie .

Comment: So what is the bug, are cookies being saved or is the detection code not working? If the cookies are being written, than this is a super user issue.

Comment: @epascarello, Cookies are being saved, but it should not be saved as I have already blocked using advance setting for First Party and Third Party cookies as above. The cookies detection code is setting the cookie and reading it. Is it any IE Advance Setting issue?

Comment: Are you sure you removed any previously existing cookies after you changed those settings?