# Why IE 11 could not able to check browser cookie enabled or disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Why IE 11 could not able to check browser cookie enabled or disabled by using below script?

```
var browser_cookie = navigator.cookieEnabled;
```

Is there any way to find out the IE browser cookie is enabled or disabled in settings. I just want to find out in java script

Please help to resolve.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Don't tag javascript stuff as java. java is not javascript

Comment: sorry. noted down

Answer (score 0):

It works for me though.

[image: IE 11 Cookie]

But if you want a better way to detect whether cookie is enabled, you can try this, code from:

[How to detect that JavaScript and/or Cookies are disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603289/how-to-detect-that-javascript-and-or-cookies-are-disabled)

```
function checkCookie(){
    var cookieEnabled = navigator.cookieEnabled;
    if (!cookieEnabled){ 
        document.cookie = "testcookie";
        cookieEnabled = document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie")!=-1;
    }
    return cookieEnabled || showCookieFail();
}

function showCookieFail(){
  // do something here
}


// within a window load,dom ready or something like that place your:
checkCookie();
```