# IE 11 issue need to show prompt when cookies are disabled

Tags: javascript

Required to show an alert when cookies are disabled in IE browser, used the below code

```
var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == "undefined" && !cookieEnabled) {
    document.cookie = "testcookie";
    cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false;
}
// navigator.cookieEnabled == true
if (cookieEnabled == false)
    alert();
```

but even the cookies are enabled or disabled in IE always getting true (cookies enable) only, any solution to handle this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: yeah, because you set `document.cookie` and check if `document.cookie` exists, which will always be the case, because you set it..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603289/how-to-detect-that-javascript-and-or-cookies-are-disabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect that JavaScript and/or Cookies are disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603289/how-to-detect-that-javascript-and-or-cookies-are-disabled)

Comment: Hi Jack thanks for the reply, I checked the link and try to implement based on the reference provided but still even at the cookie enabled or disabled both the condition it was getting the true condition.
Need only at the time of cookies disabled.