# javascript code to prompt a message when cookies are disabled in IE 11

Tags: javascript

Hi did anyone help me to get javascript code to prompt a message when cookies are disabled in IE 11?
I tried by using "navigator.cookieEnabled" property but it was not working in IE11 returning true for every time. Searched all the posts but didn't got the exact solution which works.

Helping will be appreciated. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect that JavaScript and/or Cookies are disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603289/how-to-detect-that-javascript-and-or-cookies-are-disabled)

Comment: Read this question first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603289/how-to-detect-that-javascript-and-or-cookies-are-disabled