# django CSRF token cookie not set for some users

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

I have been getting sporadic CSRF errors in an app that is mostly working ok. I do everything as I'm supposed to do: I use `{% csrf_token %}` in my template for normal forms and in my ajax POSTs I set the `X-CSRFToken` header:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
    },
});
```

I'm even forcing the cookie to be set in all views by writing a custom Middleware that calls `get_token`

```
def CSRFForceCookieMiddleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        response = get_response(request)
        get_token(request) # Force to set cookie in all responses
        return response
    return middleware
```

Everything works OK in my localhost and in production for most users. But for some users I get 403 CSRF validation error.

I added a lot of debug info. Turns out that even if `CsrfViewMiddleware` is setting the `csrftoken` is setting the cookie in the response, in the actual browser the cookie is not set (`$.cookie('csrftoken')` is `null`). So when the ajax call is made, there is no cookie present in the request.

So, I guess this pretty much means that some users' browsers are blocking this cookie? Anyone else had this experience?

Comment: Most browsers have an option to "block all cookies". You may want to detect that in javascript and give your users a warning that some functional cookies are required for the site to work correctly. Alternatively, grab the token from a hidden input field (`{% csrf_token %}`) will add that field.

Comment: @dirkgroten this is a good answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most browsers have an option to "block all cookies". You may want to detect that in javascript and give your users a warning that some functional cookies are required for the site to work correctly. There's another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603289/how-to-detect-that-javascript-and-or-cookies-are-disabled) that shows how to do that.

Alternatively, grab the token from a hidden input field (`{% csrf_token %}` will add that field in your template). That should always work.

Comment: What I m not understanding is that the CSRF token seems to change many times, so if I have a page with many ajax POST requests, it may send the original token at page load which could have changed later

Comment: the csrf middleware compares the token sent by the form with the token in the cookie/session. They both share a common secret but the one in the form is in addition salted with a changing salt. In the end all of the salted tokens are valid because they are based on the same secret.